# Python: dynamically appending values into a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I'm new in python and the way to become an expert is going to be very long. I have a problem, with the for loop scheme shown below because I want to append all the values dynamically obtained into a specific column in a Dataframe, not in a list because I need those values ​​for other calculations that I have to do in the same for loop.

I try to be more clear, the df has 3 columns:

1. Column 1: Close Price (close)
2. Column 2: Fast Exponential moving average (fast_ema)
3. column 3: Slow Exponential moving average (slow_ema)

Now, I want to create a new column in the df called 'LastBuyPrice' and put all the values generated by the for loop into this column and not in a list as shown below.

Please suggest me a proper solution, thank You in advance for any help you can offer.

```
LastBuyPrice = []
LastBuyPrice.append(0)
adding = None

for i in range(1,len(df)):

  if (df.fast_ema[i-1] < df.slow_ema[i-1] and df.fast_ema[i] > df.slow_ema[i]): 
    adding = df.close[i]
    LastBuyPrice.append(adding)

  elif (df.fast_ema[i-1] > df.slow_ema[i-1] and df.fast_ema[i] < df.slow_ema[i]):
    LastBuyPrice.append(df.close[i])
    adding = None

  else: 
    if adding is not None:
      LastBuyPrice.append(adding)
    else:
      LastBuyPrice.append(0)

'''
```

Comment: maybe you should use `shift(1)` to create new column with values from previous row and then you don't need `i-1` - so you could work without `for`-loop. Doc: [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: If you add some example input and the expected output, we could see if there is some better way to do this. Usually you don't want to work with for loops when using pandas as it's slow.

Comment: Ok Guys, thank you very much for your answer. If I run this code I get the result expected in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63919473/python-for-loop-how-to-append-the-true-valuei-in-the-next-cellsi1-i2 .                                   
Now, wich one is the cleanest and simplest way to rewrite this code in a manner that I can do dinamically other calculationa over the obtained values?                                       I can't give you a runnable code because my data are in csv file and i don't know how to upload it. Thank you again Guys.